# Questions about SharePoint 2010 multi-language support

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, customization, multilingual

I have 2 questions about SharePoint 2010 multi-language support. My situation is this: I have installed a SharePoint site and create a web applications with two languages.

1. My customer wants that when he enters the website, Sharepoint should automatically recognize the language of the browser and set the site language. Is it possible to do this with some configurations (without writing code)?
2. I want to have my site content in two different languages and I know that this can be obtained with variations, but in my Site Collection Administration the Valitaion Menu (Validations, Validation labels, Variation log) don't show up.
   As seen in this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/04/12/variations-in-sharepoint-2010-connecting-people-with-content.aspx, the Site Collection Administration has a lot of options menu, but in my site I have only a subset of these menus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is very simple: no. When a user selects a different language, that choice will be remembered for future visits. There is however no option to make the browser language determine the default language in SharePoint without coding.

Luckily I can also give you some good news. :-) Variations are part of the publishing infrastructure. You can make them available by activating the site collection scoped feature 'SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure'.

Comment: Tom I've got a question for you: I cannot set variation to sub-sites, but I can set them in the top level site. Is that possible? I try to be clearer: I have a top level site that will only be in english. Under it I have some country sites created as sub-sites of the top level site. I want each country site to implement variation in both english and its home language. I find it difficult to do this because I can only set one variation on the top level site. Thanks again Tom!